# express-jwt authentication issue with web api

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have an application that is using the standard jwt authentication shown below and copied from the express-jwt readme.

```
app.use(jwt({
  secret: 'hello world !',
  credentialsRequired: false,
  getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
      return req.query.token;
    }
    return null;
  }
}));
```

When I hit the api, the authorization header is equal to 'Bearer hello world !'.  This equals my secret, but I am getting a 401 unauthorized thrown.  Does anyone have any idea why?  isn't req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1] supposed to equal the secret?

Answer (score 1):

No the Bearer is not your secret. It's a base64 encoded jwt containing (header, payload and signature). The secret is used to sign the jwt payload with the algorithm specified in the jwt header.

Read the introduction on the [official JWT website](https://jwt.io/introduction/) to understand this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonWebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) npm package to implement jwt based authentication in your express App.
This is how authentication works  :

- import jwt from the package

  const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

Set Token in login.service.js file or where ever required with appropriate data as payload :

```
 const token = jwt.sign('payload', 'secret key',
               { expiresIn: 60*60 });
   how token looks: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiYW5pcyIsImVtYWlsIjoic29tZW1lYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.FyDrUNkvDi82lYv8JioAB9Ih8vyn6Y6mY8PpUiIz8nY
```

You can decode it by pasting the token on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) website.

- Usually we store the token in cookies(before sending response in login.router.js file set the cookie as token) :

  ```
   router.get('/auth/google/callback', (req, res, next) => {
    loginCtrl.redirectGoogle(req, res, next).then((result) => {
       res.cookie('userToken', token);
      res.redirect('/#/app/home');
       }, (err) => { 
       console.log("Error in authentication **[ ", err, " ]** ");
    res.redirect(500, '/#/login');
  });
  ```
- now write a middleware(authentication) that is called before every API request(authentication.router.js file).

```js
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.currentUser;
       // console.log('cookie', token);
       // to  decode token
    if (token) {
      authCtrl.verifyToken(token, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          res.clearCookie(config.UserToken);
          res.status(401).json({ error: ' Session Timeout... Please login again' });
         // console.log('token expired');

         // res.redirect('/#/login');
        } else {
          req.user = decoded;
          next();
        }
               // console.log('Token verified');
               // res.cookie(config.cookie.name,successResult.authToken);
      });
    } else {
           // if there is no token
           // return an error
      return res.status(403).send({
        message: 'User not authenticated.',
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
   // console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
});
```

- Inside verifyToken function which is inside auth.controller.js file we 
  decode the token :

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const verifyToken = (usertoken, done) => {
  jwt.verify(usertoken,'secret key', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    return done(null, res);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  verifyToken,
};
```

Now you API endpoints are are protected with authentication. Make sure The authentication middleware is place at top in app.js file.

```js
router.use('/login', require('./modules/login'));
router.use('/logout', (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie(userToken);
  res.redirect('/');
});
router.use(require('./modules/authentication'));
// Each Module to be placed after this
router.use('/communityMembers',require('./modules/communitymember'));
```